# Android: Can't import class from another module

Tags: android

I have an Android app module, an Android library module `:foo`, and a pure java module `:bar`. In `:foo`, I have a `Foo` class, and in `:bar`, I have a `Bar` class.

I would like to reference `Foo` from my `Bar` class. When I hover over the `Foo` variable, Android Studio gives me the following suggestion:

> Add dependency on module 'MyApplication.foo.main'

[image]

When I do as Android Studio suggests, it adds a dependency in `build.gradle` for the `:bar` module. After adding the suggested code, this is what my `build.gradle` looks like:

#### build.gradle (:bar)

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':foo')
}
```

Except there's one small problem; **`Foo` still can't be resolved!** Does anyone know how I can import it?

Here is what my project structure looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you cannot add an Android module as a dependency to a pure java module, which I guess makes sense.

Android Studio IDE was just suggesting something that cannot be done, which is misleading.